# c, get rid of uninitialized warning error

Tags: c, function, pointers, warnings

In function `my_func1()` in c the 1st thing I do is call another function  `my_func2()`, which always sets the pointer. `GCC` warns me that the pointer might not be set. How can I get rid of the warning?

Here's some simplified code to merely demonstrate it.

```
int bla;
void my_func2(int *ptr) {
   ptr = &bla;
}
void my_func1() {
    int *ptr;
    //ptr=0;
    my_func2(ptr);
}
```

If the line `ptr=0` is uncommented, then the warning goes away. I don't want to set the variable because it does nothing since the `my_func2()` sets it.

The `gcc` warning message is

> `warning: 'ptr' is used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wuninitialized]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `my_func2` doesn't do _anything_ (observable). Your compiler is right, ptr is unitialized.

Comment: It sets the ptr. I said this simplified code. My function does serve a purpose.

Comment: It doesn't. It sets its local copy, and then does nothing with it, the local variable in `my_func1` doesn't change at all and stays uninitialized.

Comment: The compiler is correct, `ptr` is never set. The variable `ptr` inside `func2` is local. If you want to set the one in main, you'll have to pass func2` an `int **` and set that.

Comment: Okay, how can it set the ptr? Something like this **ptr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
int bla;
void my_func2(int **pp) {
    *pp = &bla;
}
void my_func1() {
    int *ptr;
    my_func2(&ptr);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks everyone for the help. I'll click the checkbox for your answer when I get back. It says I must wait 6 minutes. Fastest answer ever lol.